# The default value of column is missing when using 'select into table' to copy table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, default-value, select-into

As you know, we can use 'select into table' to copy table structure in sql server, but there's a problem when the column of source table has default value, the default value setting is missing in the newly created table.

So, how can I keep the default value setting? any clue? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to break it to you, but that's NOT the only thing missing. I assume by *"the default value setting"* you actually mean default constraints, i.e. [Specify Default Values for Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872.aspx) or [Defaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187083%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

The table is created using the most basic structure and does not copy *(at least the following)*

- clustered index
- any other index for that matter
- referential constraints
- any other constraints for that matter

It makes more sense when you consider this scenario

```
select a.clustered_id a_id, b.clustered_id b_id, b.name
  from tablea a
  join tableb b on ....
```

Should it create a clustered index on a_id or b_id (which may not even be unique after this JOIN)!?  Granted you're thinking of the scenario of a single table (direct clone), but that really is a very specific use case for a generic functionality.

Comment: Bad news..I didn't realize that there're so many things missing when using 'select into'. Anyway, the default constraint is the major problem in my case, since the source tables are quite simple, and yes, we're doing direct clone.

Comment: You should just uses SSMS, look for the table and start generating create scripts through to all the children constraint and index objects.